# Узнать размеры пикселей изображения

Tags: php

Всем привет, не могу сделать функцию обработки фотографии, а точнее необходимо получить размеры изображения.
Делаю с помощью функции `getimagesize()` - он же не может найти никакой файл, даже если он существует.

```
$c_photo['new_image'] = './pht/' . $id . "/"."m_". $info['file_name']; // путь нового файла

$c_photo['source_image'] = './pht/' . $id . "/" . $info['file_name']; // Путь существующего

//Здесь необходимо получить размеры новой картинки и присвоить $width - ширину, а $height - Высоту

if($width > $height){

$c_photo['width'] = $height;

$c_photo['height'] = $height;

}else{

$c_photo['width'] = $width;

$c_photo['height'] = $width;

}

//Далее обрезаем изображение по заданным параметрам...
```

Кто знает, как правильно реализовать? За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все это не очень сложно. Если что-то не понятно пишите.

```
 if (empty($_FILES['fupload1']['name']))
    {
    //если переменной не существует (пользователь не отправил изображение),то присваиваем ему заранее приготовленную картинку с надписью "нет аватара"
    $avatar1 = "avatars/net-avatara.jpg"; //можете нарисовать net-avatara.jpg или взять в исходниках
    }

    else 
    {
    //иначе - загружаем изображение пользователя
    $path_to_90_directory1 = 'avatars/';//папка, куда будет загружаться начальная картинка и ее сжатая копия

    if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/',$_FILES['fupload1']['name']))//проверка формата исходного изображения
      {

      $filename1 = $_FILES['fupload1']['name'];
      $source1 = $_FILES['fupload1']['tmp_name']; 
      $target1 = $path_to_90_directory1 . $filename1;
      move_uploaded_file($source1, $target1);//загрузка оригинала в папку $path_to_90_directory

     if(preg_match('/[.](GIF)|(gif)$/', $filename1)) {
     $im1 = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_90_directory1.$filename1) ; //если оригинал был в формате gif, то создаем изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
     }
     if(preg_match('/[.](PNG)|(png)$/', $filename1)) {
     $im1 = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_90_directory1.$filename1) ;//если оригинал был в формате png, то создаем изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
     }

     if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/', $filename1)) {
      $im1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_90_directory1.$filename1); //если оригинал был в формате jpg, то создаем изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
     }

    // dest - результирующее изображение 
    // w - ширина изображения 
    // ratio - коэффициент пропорциональности

    // создаём исходное изображение на основе 
    // исходного файла и определяем его размеры 
    $w_src1 = imagesx($im1); //вычисляем ширину
    $h_src1 = imagesy($im1); //вычисляем высоту изображения

             // создаём пустую квадратную картинку 
             // важно именно truecolor!, иначе будем иметь 8-битный результат

             // вырезаем квадратную серединку по x, если фото горизонтальное 
             if ($w_src1>$h_src1) 
       {
       $w1 = 800;
             $h1 = 534;
       $dest1 = imagecreatetruecolor($w1,$h1);
             imagecopyresampled($dest1, $im1, 0, 0,
                              round((max($w_src1,$h_src1)-min($w_src1,$h_src1))/2),
                              0, $w1, $h1, min($w_src1,$h_src1), min($w_src1,$h_src1)); 
       }

             // вырезаем квадратную верхушку по y, 
             // если фото вертикальное (хотя можно тоже серединку) 
             if ($w_src1<$h_src1)
       {
       $w1 = 532;
             $h1 = 800;
       $dest1 = imagecreatetruecolor($w1,$h1);
             imagecopyresampled($dest1, $im1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w1, $h1,
                              min($w_src1,$h_src1), min($w_src1,$h_src1)); 
       }

             // квадратная картинка масштабируется без вырезок 
             if ($w_src1==$h_src1) 
       {
       $w1 = 800;
             $h1 = 534;
       $dest1 = imagecreatetruecolor($w1,$h1);
             imagecopyresampled($dest1, $im1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w1, $h1, $w_src1, $w_src1); 
       }

    $dat=date();
    $date=time(); //вычисляем время в настоящий момент.
    imagejpeg($dest1, $path_to_90_directory1.$_POST["login"].$dat.$date."1.jpg");//сохраняем изображение формата jpg в нужную папку, именем будет текущее время. Сделано, чтобы у аватаров не было одинаковых имен.

    //почему именно jpg? Он занимает очень мало места + уничтожается анимирование gif изображения, которое отвлекает пользователя. Не очень приятно читать его комментарий, когда краем глаза замечаешь какое-то движение.

    $avatar1 = $path_to_90_directory1.$_POST["login"].$dat.$date."1.jpg";//заносим в переменную путь до аватара.

    $delfull1 = $path_to_90_directory1.$filename1; 
    unlink ($delfull1);//удаляем оригинал загруженного изображения, он нам больше не нужен. Задачей было - получить миниатюру.
    }
    else 
             {
       //в случае несоответствия формата, выдаем соответствующее сообщение

    exit ("Аватар должен быть в формате <strong>JPG,GIF или PNG</strong>"); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

          }
    //конец процесса загрузки и присвоения переменной $avatar адреса загруженной авы
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно же за ваш код, но он мне не пригодился, так как у меня уже вся система была готова, но только маленькой детали не хватало, но ваш код подтолкнул меня на решение. Еще раз спасибо. )